# Dynamically show and hide Checkout Agreement (Terms & Conditions)?

Tags: magento2, checkout, terms-and-conditions

Based on some quote details (e.g. products in the quote) I need to show or hide a certain Checkout Agreement. The same as described here, but for Magento 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567937/magento-have-terms-and-conditions-if-customer-buys-certain-products

I have not yet been able to find a solution for Magento 2.

I know how to get the quote details and determine if the agreement needs to be shown, but I do not know where to hook into the agreement loading to stop a particular agreement from being shown if my conditions are met.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can write plugins for the corresponding module functions where you can add/delete agreements as you wish. Just do not forget to also modify the validation of the required agreements.

```
<?php

namespace XXX\XXX\Plugin\Model;

class CheckoutAgreementsListPlugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function afterGetList(\Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\CheckoutAgreementsList $subject, $result)
    {
        // modify shown agreements
        return $result;
    }

    public function afterGetRequiredAgreementIds(\Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\AgreementsProvider $subject, $result)
    {
        // modify required agreements
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Note: The subject of the plugin functions tell you which classes to override in di.xml.

```
<type name="Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\AgreementsValidator">
     <plugin sortOrder="1" name="XXXAgreementsValidator" type="xxx\xxx\Plugin\Model\CheckoutAgreementsListPlugin"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\AgreementsProvider">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="XXXAgreementsProvider" type="xxx\xxx\Plugin\Model\CheckoutAgreementsListPlugin"/>
</type>
```